# kubectl apply with stringData in secret does not remove fields

Tags: kubernetes

(using kubernetes v1.15.7 in minikube and matching client version and minikube 1.9.0)

If I `kubectl apply` a secret like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  MY_KEY: dmFsdWUK
  MY_SECRET: c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQK
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
```

then subsequently `kubectl apply` a secret removing the MY_SECRET field, like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  MY_KEY: dmFsdWUK
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
```

The `data` field in the result is what I expect when I `kubectl get` the secret:

```yaml
data:
  MY_KEY: dmFsdWUK
```

---

However, if I do the same thing using `stringData` instead **for the first kubectl apply**, it does not remove the missing key on the second one:

First `kubectl apply`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
stringData:
  MY_KEY: value
  MY_SECRET: supersecret
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
```

Second `kubectl apply` (stays the same, except replacing `MY_KEY`'s value with `b2hubyEK` to show the configuration DID change)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  MY_KEY: b2hubyEK
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
```

`kubectl get` result after applying the second case:

```
data:
  MY_KEY: b2hubyEK
  MY_SECRET: c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQ=
```

The field also does not get removed if the second case uses `stringData` instead. So it seems that once `stringData` is used once, it's impossible to remove a field without deleting the secret. Is this a bug? Or should I be doing something differently when using `stringData`?

Comment: found a related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/89938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that stringData is a write only field. It doesn’t have convergent behavior so it breaks the merge patch generator system. Most high level tools fix this by converting to normal `data` before dealing with the patch.

Answer (score 3):

kubectl apply need to merge / patch the changes here. How this works is described in [How apply calculates differences and merges changes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#how-apply-calculates-differences-and-merges-changes)

I would recommend to use *kustomize* with `kubectl apply -k` and use the **[secretGenerator](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/reference/kustomize.html#secretgenerator)** to create a unique secret name, for every change. Then you are practicing *Immutable Infrastructure* and does not get this kind of problems.

A brand new tool for config manangement is [kpt](https://googlecontainertools.github.io/kpt/guides/consumer/apply/), and `kpt live apply` may also be an interesting solution for this.